# Popup Bottom Navbar in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to achieve this in Bootstrap 4:
https://jsfiddle.net/edz80vw5/

But:

```
<li class="dropup">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="true"> <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Just produces a popup box in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `fixed-bottom` Navbar in Bootstrap 4...

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-bottom">...</nav>
```

If you want a dropdown *inside* the `fixed-bottom` Navbar to also open upwards, use "dropup"...

```
   <li class="nav-item dropup">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropup
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        </div>
   </li>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/iNxFzV2H0J